# How to validate whether the correct SMK has been restored?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, disaster-recovery, service-master-key

Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-service-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Assuming during a DR event I am provided with the SMK file, system db files and user db files, with the end goal of reviving a SQL server, then, is there any way to validate whether the SMK (that I force restore) actually pertains to those system/user databases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proactively, not really, no. The databases will need to be restored in order to test or check.

Comment: You mean databases that have some kind of certificate, yes?

Comment: If the databases don't have a master key, there is nothing to protect so it won't matter what SMK the instance currently has loaded. If there is a DMK, none of that information is shown via database backup mechanisms, so again you won't know.